# How to get XMLTransform() to handle UTF-8 on ColdFusion2018 on Windows with IIS-10?

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8, coldfusion, iis-10

Here's my code:

```
<cfset myXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>I’m coming from the XML.</foo>'>
<cfsavecontent variable="myXSL"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <output>
        I’m coming from the XSLT.
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </output>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset result = XMLTransform(myXML, myXSL)>
<cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput>
```

And here is my result:

```
Iâ€™m coming from the XSLT. Iâ€™m coming from the XML.
```

I am running CF2018 on Windows with IIS-10. It may be that this is an IIS-10 issue as I've tried this same code on a Mac/Apache setup and it works fine there. If that's the issue, how do I get IIS-10 to use UTF-8 for XML and XSLT files?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file that contains the code you posted here? Under `Setting Sumary` in CFAdmin you see `Java File Encoding`. What does it read? I'd say your file is UTF8 but your JAVA is not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable set to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and then restarting CF fixed the problem:

[image: Adding JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable]